# regular expression pattern handling brackets

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression pattern that is able to handle the following problem:

`(to make someone) happy (adj.)`

I only want to get the word "happy" and the regular expression pattern should also handle lines if only one part is in brackets e.g.:

- `(to make someone) happy`
- `happy (adj.)`

I've tried the following: `"\s*\(.*\)"`
But I am somehow wrong with my idea!

Comment: Are you trying to get the text that is not in parentheses?

Comment: yes I only try to get the text that is not in parentheses!

Answer (score 2):

This one will get you the right word in the first capturing group in all three options:

```
(?:\([^)]*\)\s*)?(\w+)(?:\s*\([^)]*\))?
```

You can adjust and be more permissive in case you'd like to get a couple of words or to allow special characters:

```
(?:\([^)]*\)\s*)?([^()\n]+)(?:\s*\([^)]*\))?
```

Comment: What if the wanted word contains special characters?

Comment: In such a case you can change to (?:\([^)]*\)\s*)?([^()\n]+)(?:\s*\([^)]*\))?

Comment: So provide that better answer, and not one which will lead him to ask what I just asked you in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

A regex for finding the text between two parenthesized groups is

```
/(?:^|\([^)]*\))([^(]*)(?:$|\([^)]*\))/m
```

The breakdown is a follows:

1. Start with some text in parentheses or the beginning of a line: `(?:^|\([^)]*\))`. This matches from an open paren to the first closed paren
2. Then match the text outside of the parentheses, and put it in a group `([^(]*)`. This matches up to the next open paren.
3. Then match more text in parentheses or the end of a line: `(?:$|\([^)]*\))`

I used multiline mode (`m`) so that `^` and `$` would match line breaks as well as the start and end of the string

Comment: yes this wont work for my second and third example if the word is not between two parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try regex `(?:^|\))\s*([^\(\)]+?)\s*(?:\(|$)`

Comment: The \\ inside your character class are obsolete. Brackets inside character groups are already escaped.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka - Yes, **most** characters in **most** regex compilers (not `-` inside or `[` or `]` or backslash at any position!). As OP didn't mentioned programming language, I better keep escape characters in pattern, as it does nothing wrong...

Comment: your relgular expression looks pretty good but if you have a ! after happy it wouldn't work for example.

Comment: @senna - Are you sure? That does not make sense!